# How to connect different computers to use their computing powers and RAMs together?

Tags: integration-testing, cluster-computing, mathematical-optimization

I have access to about 50 computers which all have 8 GB of RAM and possibly good processors like Intel i5 or Xeon. I wish to use them together for computing large optimization problems which would generally not give feasible results in only 8GB machines (I have tried such a problem using Gurobi from Python, on 16 GB RAM systems using 64 bit Intel Xeon processors and Gurobi was not able to find even the first feasible solution even when it was allowed to run for 86400 seconds).

How do I develop such a thing so that the computers' can access each others' resources and RAM? [Possibly similar to developing something like these but at smaller lab scales: https://einsteinathome.org/]. How to connect different computers to use their computing powers and RAMs together?

#cluster-computing #mathematical-optimization #integration-testing

Comment: Black-box distribution of process-work won't work in general (cpu speed vs. memory-hierarchies). To make things work in general, one needs a white-box approach: software needs to be adapted. Two remarks: 1) It's well-known, that people overestimate the potential of distributed solving in combinatorial-optimization (intro? `Koch et al. "Could we use a million cores to solve an integer program?"` 2) Gurobi seems to provide distributed solving. If you are into distributed solving, use it (and no black-box approach).  IBMs Cplex recently deprecated it's support for this (hint towards 1?).

Comment: 8 GB RAM is very small:  you can only solve small models with that.